# How do I process data in chronological order in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a key-value RDD, key is a timestamp (femto-second resolution, so grouping buys me nothing) and I want to reduce it in the chronological order.

**How do I do that in spark?**

I am fine with reducing contiguous sections of the set separately and then aggregating the resulting objects locally.

Comment: Why doesn't grouping work if you are ok with aggregating cluster reductions?

Comment: You are looking for repartitionandsort followed by aggregateByKey

Comment: @JustinPihony: because all my keys are unique - nothing happens in the same femto-second.

Comment: @ayanguha: any chance you could turn your comment into a detailed answer which I could accept? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for asking....I will do that in the evening

Answer (score 0):

You can use repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions.

Comment: kindly let me know it works. Else please post some data and expected outcome, so we can help better....

Comment: please expand your reply with links and examples.

Comment: Sure, if you can provide some test data and expected outcome, it would be easier for me :)